# DB2 sql error code -245 for a date

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am reading several sql queries from database inside a loop as below:

```
{ // start of loop
 Map<String, Object> queryRS = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(this.querySql,queryParam);
 String query = (String) queryRS.get("QUERY");

// code here as explained below

} // end of loop
```

The query returned could have any number of parameters. However, in all of them I have to set same date as the parameter.

For this I am counting the number of occurrence of character `?` in the query and creating an `Object` array with same date repeated as below.

```
String date = '2010-12-31';
int numArgs = StringUtils.countMatches(query, "?");
String[] paramArgs = new String[numArgs];
for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; i++) {
        paramArgs[i] = date;
}
```

After which I am executing the query as below:

```
SqlRowSet myRowSet = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query,(Object[]) paramArgs);
```

However, this is giving error when the query has a `Date(?)` function.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-245, SQLSTATE=428F5, SQLERRMC=DATE;1, DRIVER=3.64.96
```

The description of above error is:

```
An untyped parameter marker is passed to a function and there are two or more possible candidate functions to resolve to during function resolution.
```

What is the solution to this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using String jdbcTemplate.

I had not the same but a similar problem: the function was `char(?)` and I was 
passing an integer argument to it.
I was using a Old framework Ibatis 2.x (now I use MyBatis 3.x).
The framework was not the error cause.
On Ibatis I pass the argument so: `char(#value:INTEGER#)`
On my develop server all was work well but on remote production server I get your same error.

The problem was caused by the JDBC driver version 4.x on develop end 1.x on production.
To solve my problem I have two ways:

- change the production driver (but I cannot)
- use a different call: `char('$value:INTEGER$')` (I do this)

In IBATIS/MYBATIS framework, if value is 123, `char('$value:INTEGER$')` is translate to sql `char('123')` so solve my problem and when production change driver I can put back to `char(#value:INTEGER#)`.

You have a similar problem. Try to:

- look at the driver version
- use type like in [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForRowSet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-), [sql type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.DATE), [spring manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-type-information)

I do not use direct access to jdbcTemplate but I think that you have not to put args in string, you have to create a Date variable end put it in an Object array.

I hope that this can help you.